# Power Query - Sequentially updating multiple other columns on each row of a given column

Tags: excel, powerquery, forecasting

I am ultimately attempting to forecast inflation (`PeriodInflation`) on a retrospective per-period, rolling-history basis starting from CPI figures. So I have data up to a certain point, and `null` afterwards until the expected end of my dataset.

[image: sample of dataset]

I derive the expected trend of similarity scores (currently labelled `MeanMaxSimilarity`) and then use that to forecast 1 period into the future by multiplying it against the current `Max`. What I need to do at this point is update each `PeriodInflation` wherever there is `null` by referencing prior history of any given column. Then in that same row, I want to subsequently update the other columns (`Max`, `MaxSimilarity`, etc.) before moving on to the next row of `PeriodInflation`.

So basically:

1. Update a given row `X` of `PeriodInflation`; if `null` multiply the previous `MeanMaxSimilarity` against the previous `Max`. If not `null`, keep the value as-is.
2. Update `Max` of `X`, then `MaxSimilarity` of `X`, then `MeanMaxSimilarity` of `X`
3. `X` is now `X + 1`, repeat steps 1 through 3 until dataset is updated

How would I structure the code to do this? I don't need the exact script, I only need to know how to embed multiple sequential column updates within the updates of each row of `PeriodInflation`. Ideally this would be a function call.

Comment: Not enough information, but look into the `List.Accumulate` and/or `List.Generate` functions.